# Characters like &#x27; in Django Template. Probably unicode error

Tags: django, django-templates, python-unicode

I have in Django view the following string

```
string = "'DE', 'FR', 'IT'"
```

which is transfered to a template:

```
return render(request, 'template.html', {'string':string})
```

In the template I get this string as follows:

```
&#x27;DE&#x27;,&#x27;FR&#x27;,&#x27;IT&#x27;
```

The problem is that this ' symbol gets a strange translation;
How shall I transfer this string to template?
Thank you

Comment: This is not a strange symbol, this is simply the HTML encoding. Characters like `"`, `<`, etc. are not valid html text (since these are used for html tags).

Comment: try adding `safe`  to string in your template `{{ string|safe }}`

Comment: OK. Thank you. Instead of the string I transfered the queryset to the template. And in the template extracted single values. `{{ string|safe }}` did not work.

Comment: @Jacek B Budzynski  trick worked for me. Thanks Jacek :-)

Answer (score -1):

##### You can use:

`{{ string|safe }}`

### **But:**

If using the safe filter doesn't work for your *queryset*, you might need to adjust your approach slightly. Since you're passing a *queryset* to the template, you **can't** directly apply the safe filter to the entire *queryset*. Instead, you'll need to **iterate** over the `queryset` in the template and apply the safe filter to individual values.

Here's how you can modify your template to achieve this:

```py
{% for item in queryset %}
    {{ item|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Replace `queryset` with the name of your *queryset* variable in the template. This loop will iterate over each item in the *queryset* and apply the safe filter to each item individually, preventing Django from escaping HTML entities within each item.

**Make sure that the individual items in your queryset contain the HTML entities you expect, and applying the safe filter to each item should render them correctly in your template.**